# How do I find the "Preferences" menu in Eclipse in OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, preferences

In installing PyDev in eclipse, I need to go to `window > preferences > pydev` . . .

But when I click on Window, there is no preferences option, and I can't find it elsewhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not under the application  menu?  (E.g. the word "Eclipse" next to the Apple logo.)  I don't have Eclipse installed on my Mac, but I'd think that's where it'd be (as with most Mac applications).

Comment: There it is.  I'm a bit new to OS X.  And my search was evidently less than thorough.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Preferences is under the Eclipse menu on Mac OS X (contrary to Windows / Linux where its in the Window menu).

Comment: any why is that placed in such location?

Comment: I've no idea, but I believe that is standard on Mac OS X.

Comment: In the newer version, click on 'Eclipse` (Top left, next to apple menue). Then click, on `settings` or `preferences` (whichever is available). The opened page is titled as preferences :)

Answer (score 13):

Go to "Eclipse" on menu bar an then select "Preferences", or just key in <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
[image: Preference on Eclipse]

Comment: For those who are getting crazy, latest versions of eclipse, in the above picture, instead of Preferences, you'll see `Settings`. Once clicked, the page is titled as `preferences` :)

Answer (score 3):

In OS X you can generally get to the preferences using `Command + ,` (works for me with Eclipse on Snow Leopard).

Comment: Good enough, but it still baffles me that it wasn't available through the menus.

Comment: Don't have my MacBook here, but I will check when I am home. Its gotta be somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For Spring-Tool-Suite also it is same as Eclipse in MacOS.[image]

Answer (score 1):

On your OSX, if you still can not find Preference under Window, use the Search under Help to get to it or you can find it under Eclipse just beside the Apple logo.

Comment: I think the accepted answer has this information. This question is really old, was there a reason to add an answer after nearly five years?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under Eclipse->Prefrences[image]

Comment: This question is ten years old. Best to answer new questions, if you want to help people.